# Could not place the RSSI of WiFi networks in a list

Tags: android, android-listview, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

My code is not giving the list of RSSI of the nearby WiFi network.. the code is working as I was able to get the list of BSSID I think the problem is that BSSID is a string and RSSI is an integer .. I could not modify the code to list integers instead of strings .. any help! The code is shown below :

```
int [] level;

level = new int[wifiScanList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
level[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i).level));
```

I think the problem is with the part below

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,level));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.I should convert the signal level into a string inside the for loop and change its type initially to String

```
String [] signal;



signal = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
signal[i] = (String.valueOf(wifiScanList.get(i).level));

list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,signal));
```